# Global Variable and Function in Python giving Error

Tags: python, global-variables

I have two variables `x` and `y` defined in the main loop of the Python program and I created a separate module and imported that module into the Python main. But I am still getting error from the module as it say the `NameError: name 'x' is not defined`.

The following is the main routine:

```
from addition import add
x=5
y=2

ans=add()
```

the module `addition` is as follows:

```
def add():

    global x,y
    return x+y
```

Also, do I have to redeclare the library in the separate module such as numpy? since this library is already imported in the main program and I feel re-importing is quite redundant.

---

**Update**:

importing x,y into addition module give following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'add' from partially initialized module 'addition' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

---

It only works if I do this:

```
x=5
y=2
def add():
   x+y
print(add())
```

So why not other way round?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include all of your relevant code with correct indentions and variable declarations in the post - not just snippets.

Comment: global variables are only global within a single *file*. if you want to import `n_elements` from another module, you need to do `from module import `n_elements`

Comment: @MZ so n_elements is already defined in main python routine. I created another module in which I declared n_elements as global and imported that module to main python routine. I shall update a relevant code now.

Comment: @Jan I have included all relevant code.

Comment: You have a circular import: you're trying to import one thing into the main routine but you're also trying to import into the addition module – dependencies should be linear

Comment: What you're trying to do just won't work. Use parameters x and y and don't try to use globals like this

Comment: @MZ yes I solved it by passing x,y as parameters to function. The problem is that I have too many parameters. The fun fact is if I don't declare the function as separate module and create the function in the main itself, then I can do what I want to do i.e. without passing x,y as parameters and function simply adds without any issue. This is quite weird in my opinion